# Why boost::format cannot be converted directly to std::string?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-format

Following is not possible:

```
std::string s = boost::format("%d") % 1; // error
```

You have to explicitely call the method str():

```
std::string s = (boost::format("%d") % 1).str(); // OK
```

It would only be syntactic sugar, but why not just add the conversion?

Comment: Isn't the overloading of % bad enough? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for here. Are you asking if there are any semantic issues that prevent Boost from implementing such a thing? Or are you just saying, "They should have done it this way."

Comment: I am trying to understand the semantic issues. I usually think that the boost libs are well designed.

Comment: Implicit conversions are sometimes convenient, but also cause problems by hiding bugs when you really *didn't* want a conversion. Boost follows the model of std::string and std::stringstream, neither of which provide implicit conversions to their content types.

Comment: @jrok And what is bad in overloading '%'??

Comment: @jrok There is a good rationale here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/format/doc/choices.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not a very good thing if an implicit conversion can throw exceptions. Conversion to string will by default throw an exception if less arguments are fed to `format` than needed.
E.g.

```
std::string f()
{
   boost::format fmt("%d");
   // forgot to feed an argument
   std::string s = fmt;  // throws boost::io::too_few_args
   widget.set_title( fmt );  // throws boost::io::too_few_args
   return fmt;  // throws boost::io::too_few_args
}
```

Such implicit conversions make it hard to spot and analyze the parts of code that can throw exceptions. But explicit `.str()` calls provide a hint of such possible exceptions, which makes life easier when ensuring the surrounding code's exception safety, as well as (in this particular case) hinting to double-check preceding code to prevent said exception from happening in the first place.

Comment: Both answers (this and the one of BigBoss) give good reasons for not having the implicit conversion. But I had to accept only one :-)

Answer (score 11):

I think the reason for this is same as `std::stringstream`, in that context you should also use `.str()` to convert the stream to string and same for `boost::formatter` and the reason is as:

```
std::string s1 = "Hello ", s2 = "World";
format("%s.") % s1 + s2;
```

Now if `boost::formatter` was implicitly convertible to `std::string` then it produce "Hello .World", because `format("%s.") % s1` will be converted to "Hello ." and then it will be implicitly converted to `std::string` and use `operator+` to add it with `s2`, but probably most programmers want to have "Hello World." and that will be a source of error an confusion. But in the case that no implicit conversion exist compiler will generate error for this(because there is no `operator+` for `boost::formatter` and `std::string`) and for you to correct it either as `format("%s.") % (s1 + s2)` or `str( format("%s.") % s1 ) + s2`